# DocuSign Remote Signing vs Echosign

Tags: docusignapi

**Echosign** allows us to send a document to **Echosign** to sign and then Echosign sends us a URL that we can then embed in our own email and send it to the signer. DocuSign's remote signing has Docusign sending the email to the signer instead. Is there a way to do what we did in **Echosign** in Docusign?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this question Faulkner. I think you are confused about terminology.

**Remote Signing**
This means that an email is sent to the recipient with a URL that would enable them to sign on any device anywhere.

**Embedded Signing**
This means that the signing will take place inside an app. No email is sent. The app developers embed the URL for signing as part of the flow of their application.

For more information on Embedded Signing:
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/embedding

Comment: No, I'm not confused. Yes, Docusign sends the email with the link just as I said. Echosign allows you to retrieve a URL for use in your own e-mail.

Comment: Embedded signing allows you to generate the URL for the signing session and provide it to the customer, but signing session URLs are short lived - the intention is that you're only generating the signing session when the user has been authenticated by your application and is ready to sign.

Comment: DocuSign also allows you to retrieve a URL to use in your own email, I sent you the links on how to do that.  The URL does expire after a couple of minutes for security reasons, so sending it in email yourself does not make sense (if you use remote signing - the URL lasts much longer).
You can use branding and other changes in the email to make the email look like it came from you if that's what your concern is.

Comment: here is a trick you can do. You generate a URL to your app (myapp.domain.com/signthis/12910293810293 and this URL will, on the server, call the API to generate the signing URL and redirect to it on the fly. That works just fine. You email yourself the first URL to your customer. Let me know if this is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

> Re: Is there a way to do what we did in Echosign in DocuSign?

Yes, there are two solutions:

**Easier:** Change the branding of the email sent to the signer. See [docs.](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-configure-branding) You can update the colors, add your logo etc.

**More work:** Create your own "start-to-sign" url and include it in emails that you then send out. Here's the high-level flow:

Assuming that you want to send an envelope to Pat Smith to be signed. And you want to send the email link:

1. Create a record in your app's database of the signer's name, email, and other app-related information. Record the keyId of the record you've created. Note that there should be one record per recipient, not one record per envelope.
2. Create the DocuSign envelope with Pat Smith (and her email) as a signer recipient. Include recipient attribute `clientId` set to the keyId of the database record. Doing so will suppress the invite email and set the recipient as an embedded recipient. Save the resulting envelopeId
3. Update the keyId record in your app's database with the envelopeId from DocuSign.
4. Update the keyId record in your app with a new attribute of `urlId.` In this column generate a UUID. Do not use a sequence/key/etc. It is important that the `urlId` be unguessable.

Create a URL endpoint in your app. Something like https://apps.mycompany.com/thisapp/signFromEmail/[urlId]

Then, include that url (with the urlId for Pat Smith substituted for `urlId`) in your email to Pat. That will be the start-to-sign url for Pat for that envelope.

When Pat clicks on the url, your app should:

1. Look up the recipient record in your app database where urlId = the provided urlId
2. Use that record's data to create an [EnvelopeViews::createRecipient](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient) call to DocuSign. The result is a `url link` that must be used within a couple of minutes.
3. Redirect the browser to the `url link` -- Pat will then see the DocuSign signing ceremony.